# How to define an elevation in angular material 2?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

the md-toolbar in angular-material 2 doesn't have a shadow. I want to define for my toolbar

Answer (score 81):

You can use the `mat-elevation-z#`classes.

`#` can stand for a number between 1-24

```html
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z4">
  With Shadow
</mat-toolbar>
```

https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation

Comment: I used to do this, but recently I can't get it working. Is it just me, or have they changed things?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. The prefix has changed from `md-` to `mat-`.

Comment: where can i find the documentations this?

Comment: Here you can read more about the elevations in Angular material design https://medium.com/@ladyleet/adding-box-shadow-z-depth-to-angular-material-2-components-6bd0de303dcb

Comment: Check this out if anyone looks at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415537/angular-material2-toolbar-shadow in the latest version it looks like you have to set position relative and z-index to something above 1

Comment: And if you want to remove elevation you can use mat-elevation-z0

Comment: Here is the document : [Using elevation helpers](https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation), or at [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/5.0.1/guides/elevation.md)

Comment: Beyond the elevation, are there more prebuilt CSS classes for things like padding, margin and so on? In Angular Material v1 there were attributes like layout-padding or layout-margin but now in Angular Material v2 I don't find anything like this.